# Confusion about for loop in Java

Tags: java

I wrote a for loop like this:

```
for(int i = 0; (char) System.in.read() != 's'; i++){
    System.out.print(i);
}
```

I expected the program to keep printing numbers until I type `s` on the keyboard. However, every time I typed a letter, I got `three numbers` on the command prompt:

```
a
012
q
345
```

There should be only one number printed on the console after each letter typed, but there are three. Why?

Comment: i assume you type a letter followed by the Enter key?  Did you account for reading the line feed and carriage return characters?

Comment: Your issue is not with the for-loop, it is with the behavior of `System.in.read()`, which is buffered and waits until end-of-line.

Comment: I actually get two numbers in the console.

Comment: @MichaelQueue Probably because Gropai has Windows, and you have a different OS.

Comment: @Brian Goetz Why does buffering cause more numbers to be printed?

Comment: @Gropai - Because you have entered more characters than you think you have.

Comment: If this is still confusing you, why not modify your code to display the ascii values of the characters read?  That will help you understand what is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As several of your commenters stated, the issue isn't with the for() loop, but with System.in.read(), which will also provide the Carriage Return / Line Feed from the input stream as characters (they are also why your output is spread across several lines, as opposed to everything being on one line)

Comment: Then how can I fix the problem?

Comment: There are several forms of InputStream.read() (Please see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) that you can use, including one that passes a byte[] so you can retrieve all of the characters that were available at the time the for loop executed (of which you could check the content with a for ... in loop inside of your outer loop

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Answer (score 2):

Like Brian said in the comments, it's because the input is buffered. When you type `a` and then hit the enter key that enter key is flushing the buffer and you are seeing the loop execute 3 times. Once for the first character, `a`, and twice more for the `\n` and `\r` characters representing the new line and carriage return characters.